# Using Clarifai's models locally

Tags: c#, clarifai

I wanted to ask if it is possible to use Clarifai's system offline, meaning accessing the trained models on the device so it can work without access to the internet.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kunal from Clarifai here.

We support this with our Mobile SDK which is currently in limited preview. You can get more information here, https://www.clarifai.com/get-sdk